# UIView & Image Clipping in iPhone?

Tags: ios, drawrect, image-clipping

Let said I have a image which the circle in the middle is transparent and I use the drawRect function to draw sqaure like the second image below.

Then what I want to do is to get the alpha layer of the first image, the circle as a path, then apply on the square i draw and clip it and draw like the final image, just want it to draw on the circle path.

Thank in advance.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nicely asked, but please tell what have you tried?

Comment: Image clipping I have try to use the demo provided in Apple Doc, but in the end failed also, maybe I miss out something.